# Apache shows unexplained Out of memory message

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx

I am using nginx + apache in reverse proxy. Sine today all the websites hosted on my server show 502 bad gateway.
I trie to look in the log files and I found an error in apache's log file which only says "Out Of Memory".

In mysql's error log I have this :

`2017-01-12 20:02:40 140440099285760 [Warning] Aborted connection 42 to db: 'database' user: 'user' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

I have upgraded some packages yesterday. May be it is the related to the upgrade. Here is the list :

`php7.0-soap:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-mcrypt:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-mbstring:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-intl:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-imap:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-xml:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-sqlite3:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-readline:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-pspell:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-opcache:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-mysql:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-ldap:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-json:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-gd:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
libapache2-mod-php7.0:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-cli:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
php7.0-common:amd64 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
libnss3-nssdb:all 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 2:3.26.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
libnss3:amd64 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 2:3.26.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.4.0-57.78 4.4.0-59.80
unattended-upgrades:all 0.90ubuntu0.2 0.90ubuntu0.3`

May be someone has already experienced this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, as a test roll back that upgrade and check if the issue vanishes.

Comment: How to do that ? Uninstall theses packages and reinstall the old version ?

Comment: Depends on the software management system you are using. So on your type of Linux distribution.

Comment: I have downgraded all the packages related to PHP and it works now.
I suspect the problem to be in the php7.0-mysql package.
I will upgrade them one by one to see where the problem comes from.
Thanks you.

Comment: Hm, ok, not good... Actually I hesitated to upgrade my systems today, so thanks for the warning...